# Add Locate button LeafletWidget() in GeoDjango

Tags: leaflet, geodjango, button

I created a new widget that inherent from LeafletWidget() . I'm trying to add Locate Button to the map but i keep getting errors.r

Widgets.py

```
from django.forms.widgets import Widget
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from leaflet.forms.widgets import LeafletWidget


class CustomLeafletWidget(LeafletWidget):
    template_name = 'leaflet/widget.html'

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.min.css',
                    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.79.0/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.css')
        }
        js = ('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.min.js',
              'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.79.0/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.js')

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        rendered = super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        map_id = attrs['id']
        return rendered + mark_safe('''
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var map = window[map_id];
                    var lc = L.control.locate({
                        position: 'topright',
                        strings: {
                            title: "Show my location"
                        }
                    });
                    lc.addTo(map);
                });
            </script>
        ''')
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: map_id is not defined